# Convert string to json got undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having the a string Posted here. I would like to convert this string to json string. But i got the error message 'undefine' Please help me to do this.

```
data = JSON.parse('{ name: "CHE-TELUGU", value: 123, y: 10.8 },{ name: "CHE-CORPORATE", value: 45, y: 40.8 },{name: "CHE-MALAYALAM",value: 155,y: 12.8,sliced: true,selected: true},{ name: "CHE-OPERATION", value: 20, y: 60.8 },{ name: "TRY-OPERATION", value: 20, y: 60.8 } ');
                            alert(data);
```

Comment: This is simply not JSON. Names in JSON are between quotes. See http://json.org

Comment: sorry, dude. it's just not json, bro.

Comment: You can always paste your JSON to a validator to get the idea, see: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is because your string is not valid JSON for 2 reasons:

1. You objects need to be wrapped in [] as they are an array
2. Your object properties should be wrapped in double quotes

So, something like would work:

```
JSON.parse('[{ "name": "CHE-TELUGU", "value": 123, "y": 10.8 }]')
```

To help you understand more about JSON and have a play, try the following:

If you open Chrome, then open developer tools and go to the console tab, you can quickly write JS statements to test them out. For example if you try invalid JSON like JSON.parse('{ name: "CHE-TELUGU" }') - no double quotes round the property name - you will see the message 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token n'.

Likewise if you try JSON.parse('{ "name": "CHE-TELUGU" },{ "name": "CHE-TELUGU" }') - without the [] round the objects to make an array - you will see the message 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,'.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Ian Routledge has stated - your string needs to appear as:

```
[
   {
      "name" : "CHE-TELUGU",
      "value" : 123,
      "y" : 10.8
   },
   {
      "name" : "CHE-CORPORATE",
      "value" : 45,
      "y" : 40.8
   },
   {
      "name" : "CHE-MALAYALAM",
      "selected" : true,
      "sliced" : true,
      "value" : 155,
      "y" : 12.8
   },
   {
      "name" : "CHE-OPERATION",
      "value" : 20,
      "y" : 60.8
   },
   {
      "name" : "TRY-OPERATION",
      "value" : 20,
      "y" : 60.8
   }
]
```